# Simple matrix column replacement giving strange results

Tags: python, matrix

I coded this simple function for an exercise:

```
def matrix_subs(matrix, n):
    res = matrix
    for i in range(len(res)):
        res[i][n] = 20
    return res
```

and here are the results i get:

```
matrix_subs(matrix1,2)

[[2, 2, 20, 2], [4, 6, 20, 3], [2, 2, 20, 2], [0, 1, 20, 0]]

matrix_subs(matrix1,1)

[[2, 20, 20, 2], [4, 20, 20, 3], [2, 20, 20, 2], [0, 20, 20, 0]]
```

I don't understand why it is saving the res from the first time i called the function to matrix1. I wrote res = matrix in the start of the function to make res reset to the default matrix but It's not working.

Comment: They both point to the same object in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if both variables are the same object in memory you can use `print(id(res))` and `print(id(matrix))`. If I am not mistaken those will show the same memory address, which means that both variables are the same object (in memory).

What you want is to make a deepcopy, since you have nested loops:

```
from copy import deepcopy
def matrix_subs(matrix, n):
    res = deepcopy(matrix)
    for i in range(len(res)):
        res[i][n] = 20
    return res
```